# Installing Lubuntu 12.04 on a Mac G4 Powerbook

Tags: installation, dual-boot, lubuntu, mac, macosx

I recently got 3 powerbooks from a friend of mine, only one of which I intend on using. I installed Lubuntu dual boot with OSX and restarted. When the Powerbook restarts, I hear the beep, and then I see a gray screen with a box in the middle that has a question mark in it. One second later, the box changes to the finder icon, and OSX boots up.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to boot to Lubuntu and restore the Grub menu? (I assume that is what Lubuntu uses, I use Ubuntu for my main computer so I am unfamiliar with other ubuntu distros.)

The Powerbook I am using,

PowerBook G4 2004 15" aluminum

1.33 GHz PowerPC CPU

512 MB SDRAM (Will add more soon)

OSX: 10.3.9

Lubuntu 12.04 PowerPC version

Answer (score 1):

On PowerPC processor, the bootloader used by Linux is Yaboot, regardless of the distro. Same for Ubuntu and all *buntus. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaboot. So it is the yaboot menu that is not showing up yet.

I don't know why yet, because I am just learning how myself.

See [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#What_do_I_need_to_know_for_dual-booting.3F](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#What%5fdo%5fI%5fneed%5fto%5fknow%5ffor%5fdual-booting.3F)